# Syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing a script in bash and I get this error:

```
./P4.1: line 10: +: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
```

And this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read string
echo $string >| temp
num1= cut -d" " -f1 temp
num2= cut -d" " -f2 temp
num3= cut -d" " -f3 temp
while [ $num1 -gt $num3 ]
do
        echo $num1
        num1=$[$num1+$num2]
done
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Check also the `-gt` part, should't it be `-lt` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Combination of ceving and Tomek's:

```
#!/bin/bash
read num1 num2 num3
while [ $num1 -lt $num3 ]
do
    echo $num1
    num1=$((num1+num2))
done
```

Comment: Yes, the string seems to be the problem

Comment: I need to get the input as a whole string and then divide it up. Why do you use $(( )) instead of $[ ] like I was tought?

Comment: Well, either way is correct. You can do whichever one you choose. And this should read the numbers and it should divide them up. It reads the numbers all at once, delimited by spaces, and they are already separated when read.

Comment: or: `for ((; num1 < num3; num1 += num2)); do echo $num1; done`

Answer (score 8):

Use round parenthesis for numeric computations:

```
num1=$((num1 + num2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read string
echo "${string}" >| temp
num1= cut -d" " -f1 temp
num2= cut -d" " -f2 temp
num3= cut -d" " -f3 temp
while [ "${num1}" -gt "${num3}" ]
do
    echo "${num1}"
    num1=$(expr "${num1}" + 1)
done
```

also, quote and brace your variables. :D

Answer (score 0):

try
`num1=$[ num1 + num2 ]`
may remove the error ~

Answer (score 0):

hi i know it has been nearly 10 years since this questin was asked but perhaps using $((.....)) around airthmatic operations help

```
$((num1 + num2))
```