# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")

Tags: bash, operand

Could anyone point out what's wrong with the below line from a bash script I'm using?

```
if [ "$(( $(date +"%s")-$(stat -c "%Y" $SENDDIR/$NIGHTLY_FILE) ))" -gt "3600" ]; then
```

I receive the error noted in the subject line.

I had copied the script from one server to another thinking that it should work but alas, no.

Comment: wrap that line with `set -vx` above and `set +vx` below so you can see how the variables are being expanded. Then it should be very easy to see where the problem is with you math values. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter,  Thanks for the input. With that enabled this is the output:  
    date +"%s") -$(stat -c "%Y" $SENDDIR/$NIGHTLY_FILE)  
    date +"%s"
    ++ date +%s  
    stat -c "%Y" $SENDDIR/$NIGHTLY_FILE)  
    stat -c "%Y" $SENDDIR/$NIGHTLY_FILE ++ stat -c %Y  
    /senddir/nightly_file.xml stat: cannot stat /senddir/nightly_file.xml': No such file or directory  
./file.sh: line 75: 1386560712 - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")  
  I've looked it over but am not sure how to interpret the output.  edit: Apologies about the lack of formatting.

Comment: Does `/senddir/nightly_file.xml` exist?  The error seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Bingo.  The rudimentary script was fine.  A particular directory the script relies on was not where it should have been on the new server.  Thank you both for the input!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176640/syntax-error-operand-expected-error-token-is)