# Bash script syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")

Tags: bash, syntax

What I need to do is to cut a long text file into 10 peaces with same count of lines. Therefore I wrote the following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
count=0
file=0
br=$(wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1}')
let br = $br/10
while read -r line
do
let count = count + 1
    name="$line"
echo $name >> file$file.csv
if [ $count = $br ];then
let count=0
let file+=1
fi
done < "$filename"
```

The scripts produces the following error which I do not understand

```
cut.sh: line 9: let: =: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
```

I have read [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176640/syntax-error-operand-expected-error-token-is) but still could not find a solution. 
Any ideas are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Just copy/paste your script on shellcheck.net and fix all syntax errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` variable assignment can not have whitespace around `=`. Drop the spaces around `=`:

```
let br=${br}/10
```

Do the same for all such cases.

Comment: Very well. Do you have any idea why the result produces a different count of lines in first and last output file, just by the way?

Comment: @JürgenK. You have not provided enough data for me to get to a conclusion.

Comment: In my case the first file contains 95k of lines. The next 9 files around 16 k und the last file only 5 lines. I don't understand why the first file is that large. While the input file is 164k of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically calculations in bash need to be enclosed in double brackets and so:

```
let count=$(( $count + 1 ))
```

Comment: `let` evaluates its arguments as arithmetic expansions, you don't need `$(( ))` with it. Either `let count=count+1` or `count=$((count+1))` is fine.